# I am trying to install kivy but keep getting errors when I try to install the dependency's

Tags: python, windows, kivy

The error is

```
 error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [10 lines of output]
      Collecting setuptools
        Using cached setuptools-68.2.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (6.3 kB)
      Collecting wheel
        Using cached wheel-0.41.3-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.2 kB)
      Collecting packaging
        Using cached packaging-23.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.2 kB)
      Collecting cython!=0.27,!=0.27.2,<=0.29.33,>=0.24
        Using cached Cython-0.29.33-py2.py3-none-any.whl (987 kB)
      ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement kivy_deps.gstreamer_dev~=0.3.3 (from versions: none)
      ERROR: No matching distribution found for kivy_deps.gstreamer_dev~=0.3.3
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

It should have installed kivy am I doing something wrong

Comment: `python -m pip install Kivy`